# Can Lua 'Timeout"?

Tags: lua

Lets say I am running a script and the game client waits for the script to be finished before it updates.  Can Lua do somthing of a 'timeout'?  Like, can i set a priority on the update  so it leaves the script to do the update and then after words could it go back to where it was in the script?

Comment: I think you are better of with multithreading. One thread for the Lua script, another one for the updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a count hook with a suitable count for timeout and abort execution of the script in the hook.

Answer (score 0):

Lua uses collaborative multithreading, so the script must know how long it has taken before it passes control back to the caller. Its not hard to figure out how long it has run using os.time and getting the difference. In some cases this might be more difficult, but if the script is a loop it shouldn't be hard. Once you've figured out that you've run for too long, do a coroutine.yield() and when you want to resume the script, simply call lua_resume from your update loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your whole lua_State and lua script in another thread. When the Lua script accesses functions you implemented which need to modify things in the main thread, use mutexes and other things to make that access thread-safe.

This way, you can easily have your Lua script hang or do whatever while your main thread can continue to operate normally, however, it also requires you to make all your implemented functions accessing anything the main thread probably takes care of normally (like graphics) to be threading-aware.