# Setting timeout for embedded Lua

Tags: c++, c, lua

I have embedded Lua in a C/C+= application. I want to be able to set a timeout value to prevent getting trapped with badly written scripts that can result in infinite loops (or even string searches that take an infinite time to complete).

Basically, I want to be able to set a time interval and if the script fails to complete running at the end of that time interval, I want to be able to kill the Lua script engine (gracefully, if possible).

Anyone knows of best practise way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656754/can-lua-timeout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777527/stopping-a-runaway-lua-subprocess

Answer (score 3):

One way to control the amount of time a script takes is to set a count hook and then raise an error in the hook. But this does not work if the script can call C functions that may take a long time.